# Why does DropDownList.SelectedValue is relied on viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, forms, viewstate

If I set on my page : `EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Disabled"` - Then  - the Viewstate is disable for the page ( *unless override...*)

Then, trying to read from (*assuming the control has been populated in the last dump to the screen and a value is selected*):

`MyDDL.SelectedValue` will yield `""`

That's because of disabled viewstate :

But my question is at a higher level :

- If it's all about a form value (which I still can get from `Request.Form[MyDDL.UniqueID]`) -  and we're talking about an input which doesn't need anything to save its value.
- **Why** does the `DropDownList` property named (`SelectedValue`)  Is relied on ViewState ?

p.s. the TextBox **onchangeevent** does rely on viewstate although the control is an input (which doesnt need viewstate) - it saves the value of the text and then it compare it when postback.But it only relies on viewstate when you set onchange event ( and autopostback)

Comment: Well textbox value do not rely on viewstate you can disable viewstate and you will still get textbox value ,Its value comes from  IPostBackDataHandler . Request.Form[""] Works only when you are submitting your data using POST method , Consider a user is unable to submit a form due to validation errors or any error by which your form can not be posted at that event you can't get your values from Request.Form[""] .

Comment: @surajsingh I already know that. still my question remains .

Comment: Hope i am on the right track now , I just created a dropdownlist using listitems and it retains state even after disabling ViewState . I still have to check for dropdown which are bounded via database tables , Let's see if they retain their state and can i get any answer .

Comment: @surajsingh no you're not . you're not using !IsPostBack

Comment: I dont have to use IsPostBack even in previous trial as i was using hardcoded values using listitems.

Comment: values are not in the DDL when it's back from page

Comment: You can get dropdownlist selected value from Request.Form[""] , As Viewstate also uses Request.Form[""] keys to send them to server during server trips.

Comment: It was by mistake my bad ! damn mouse ,well i tried to upvote but your question needed to edited to upvote again , Hope you don't mind if i edit , Sorry !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SUMMARY: If you want the control to work without ViewState, you need to populate/bind the Items collection on every postback.  I recommend doing it in the Page_Init event (i.e. OnInit method).**

First off, I always recommend this this awesome article: [TRULY Understanding ViewState.](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)

The SelectedValue doesn't require ViewState. Looking at the code for ListControl, which DropDownList inherits from, we see the code:

```
public virtual string SelectedValue
{
  get
  {
    int selectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex >= 0)
      return this.Items[selectedIndex].Value;
    else
      return string.Empty;
  }
```

The important thing to take away from this code is that the Items list must be populated to get the SelectedValue.

If you utilize ViewState, the Items collection **is** persisted to / loaded from ViewState, which allows the SelectedValue property to work without rebinding the control.

Comment: So its just how it works. ( the implementation of SelectedValue....)cool. (cuz it's weird to be relied on viewstate if i only need the value....)

Answer (score 7):

The `SelectedValue` relies on `ViewState` because on PostBack it rebuilds its `ListItems` from the `ViewState` and then sets the selected value on the `DropDownList` from the `Request` Object.

It is not taking the `Request` value as the `SelectedValue` directly. This in turn is because, ASP.Net can check if the posted `DropDownList` has not been tampered with at the client. It does so by first de-serializing the original items from the `ViewState`. It then finds the `Request` Value in the items and sets its `Selected` property as `true`. Only now, the `SelectedValue` property is available. (or `SelectedIndex` for that matter). It should be able to fire a `SelectedIndexChanged` event now.

This is also the reason that you do not need to bind the `DropDownList` again in `PageLoad`. The list items are automagically retreived from the `ViewState`.

If the `ViewState` is disabled, then there will be no original list items in the `ViewState` and will be empty. Hence it will not be able to mark any item as selected. Hence the `SelectedValue` will be 0 or the `SelectedItem` will be null. I think the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will also not fire. For things to work in this case databinding needs to be done, preferably on `init`.

There are workarounds to that however.

Complete Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

**Edit**: (after Op's comments)

Following the page life cycle to see where `SelectedValue` relies on `ViewState`:

*Stage 1 Init*: The control heirarchy is built. If the DropDownList is bound here or the ListItems have been added declaratively, the List gets populated here.

*Stage 2 Load ViewState*: On PostBack, the ViewState is validated here and loaded into the DropDownList. There is **no** `SelectedValue` here.

*Stage 3 Load PostBack Data*: Here the `Request` Value (from the form request) is taken and then applied to the control. In this case of `DropDownList` it now **sets** the `SelectedValue` from the received `Request` Object Value, internal implementation is something like this:

```
string selectedValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[DropDownList_Id];
Items.FindByValue(selectedValue).Selected = true;
```

What is important here is that if ViewState is not there and DropDownList is not data-bound, then the ListItem collection will be empty and hence `SelectedValue` property is 0. This has nothing to do with internal implementation of a property.

If the ViewState is not there (disabled) and DropDownList is data-bound, then the ListItem collection will exist and corresponding item will be marked as selected and hence `SelectedValue` property will return the correct value.

If the item collection is new (thru a re-binding with different data set or ViewState is invalidated), then the `Request` Form value would not be found in the item collection and again `SelectedValue` will be invalid.

*Stage 4 Page Load*: by this time the ViewState (or data-binding) and PostBack Data has already been loaded.

*Stage 5 Raise PostBack Event*: At this stage the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of DropDownList is fired if the index was changed in Stage 3.

Hence, the `SelectedValue` relies on ViewState at Stage 3. Of course, if the control is appropriately data-bound then it will not rely on ViewState as a corollary.

`SelectedValue` relies on ViewState to make sure the items collection has been populated prior to setting it. Data-binding / Re-binding is just another way to make sure the items collection is populated.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: the  tampered issue is checked with validationMAc. it has nothing to do with selectedvalue.

Comment: _ it will not be able to mark any item as selected_ , right. but it should have a value (IMHO) like the request.form

Comment: `"it has nothing to do with selectedvalue"`, SelectedValue is set after ViewState has been validated. See the page life cycle events. I will update the answer to make it more clear after some time.

Comment: See the internal implementation of the property in that reference, I didn't repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    string qry = "SELECT TOP(5)xxx, xxxx FROM dbo.xxxxxx ";
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds = SqlHelper.ExecInDS(qry);
                    drpDwn.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    drpDwn.DataValueField = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Columns["xxx"]);
                    drpDwn.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Columns["xxx"]);                   
                    drpDwn.DataBind();
                }
               //Here You will get selected value from dropdown
               string sss= Request.Form["drpDwn"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DropDownList  to work without ViewState, you can bind the control in page_load only once  as given below:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {        
     //whatever you use declarative binding (in aspx page), or define data source  here
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                  ddl.DataBind(); //fire databinding events and fill items, and selectedvalue has a value.
                }

                //you can get the selectedvalue
                var sv=ddl.SelectedValue ; //
            }
```

- In the case ( ViewState is disabled), Asp.net FrameWork retrieve the items from the back end with every PostBack.
- In the case (ViewState is enabled), Asp.net FrameWork retrieve the items from the ViewState without hitting the back end with every PostBack

Normally, the Asp.net FrameWork fire  the data binding events in PreRender event: Read [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#)

You can confirm that behavior by enabling Trace.

**SelectedValue doesn't rely directly on ViewState** from [source code of ListControl](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListControl.cs,370) , BUT depend on items as described above.